# How to recover an unfocussed image

Tags: optics, information, image-processing

If the lenses in a camera are not set correctly, the intended subject will be "out of focus" in the resulting image. There seems to be no loss of information here. The photons are just steered to the wrong CCD element. If we knew the exact specification and configuration of the lenses, would it be possible to apply a tranform on the image to see the subject in focus?

Sharpening filters are often used to improve "out of focus" images, but I suspect a much better result could be possible if the physics of the optics were considered.

Comment: Google Deconvolution. For example, see http://www.olympusmicro.com/primer/digitalimaging/deconvolution/deconintro.html. Deconvolution can correct focus errors and other defects.

Comment: Starting to read up on deconvolution. That is a deep rabbit hole.

Comment: You might want to look in to the Hubble space telescope mirror, which was incorrectly grounded but could initially be corrected with software (and eventually with a second correcting mirror)

Comment: possible duplicate of [On unfocused images, their information content and possible restoration](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/169139/on-unfocused-images-their-information-content-and-possible-restoration?rq=1)

Comment: While standing behind someone else using your computer, just say "Enhance!"

Comment: You may be interested in one of my [answers on the Mathematica SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83385/21750) where, with a careful setup, a fairly good image can be recovered.

Comment: @2012rcampion That is a comprehensive answer. I did not realise that such restoration was possible. Also a good explanation of why the signal to noise ratio is critical.

Comment: @igael what exactly are you looking for to be answered. And why is the accepted answer not sufficient? (or is your account hacked?)

Comment: @BruceLee : it is well answered. I hope to read the approachs based on half-quadratic inferences, random fields, cases with models, homogeneity of the samples and cascades strategies. Objects magnification in the astronomic images use most of them ( furthermore remember Hubble ). No, no, the account is not hacked, I think that it is the best usage of points and each must do the same :)

Comment: I agree with the fact that is not exactly a physics question ( maths and/or enginerring ) , the Acouriousone answer is very clever but Riddler gave only a link to the answers. I really don't know what to do

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Unfortunately there is a loss of information for physical images i.e. images with finite signal to noise ratio per pixel. An out of focus lens acts like a linear transformation, i.e. a matrix between the focused ideal image and the actual image. To reverse that transformation we have to calculate the inverse of the matrix. Depending on the severity of the blurring that inverse may not exist or it may, if it exists, amplify noise and sampling errors in the resulting image very strongly. Imagine the worst case blurring matrix of a two pixel image:

$\begin{bmatrix}0.5&0.5\\0.5&0.5\end{bmatrix}$

This matrix is singular and can not be inverted at all.

Take a less severe case (20% blurring), now the matrix is

$\begin{bmatrix}0.8&0.2\\0.2&0.8\end{bmatrix}$

and the inverse of that is:

$\begin{bmatrix}4/3&-1/3\\-1/3&4/3\end{bmatrix}$

There are two problems with this one: because of negative coefficients in the inverse you may end up with negative pixel values in the reconstructed image, which is unphysical. Secondly the diagonal elements are larger than one, which amplifies noise.

Having said that, one can achieve remarkable results if the resulting image has a very high signal to noise ratio and if the inverse transformation can be reconstructed with high precision.

If you are interested in this area I would urge you to do your own experiments with a few matrices to get a feel for what's going on. Ideally image blurring is a local phenomenon, i.e. we can restrict ourselves to areas of an image that are only a few (maybe 2-5) pixels wide. This reduces the problem to small matrices. Wolfram Alpha can do the matrix inversion for you, so you don't have to set up any math package (although numpy is easy to use, if you know Python).

As for the experimental side of it, the proper way to calibrate a lens requires to produce a series of high contrast test images of either pinholes (delta functions) to retrieve the blurring matrix directly or, even better, to use high frequency stripe patterns to measure the blurring in the Fourier domain.

Comment: Comprehensive answer! I will take your suggestion and try out some matrix operations with my friend Python.

Comment: Nice answer - though strictly speaking, shouldn't you have a Tensor acting on the matrix of pixels? (Which one could of course re-shape into a matrix acting on the row-aligned pixels)

Comment: I'm not that familiar with optics, spread point functions, etc. but have worked with optical engineers who have explained the inverse focusing problem in a similar way. I agree - good explanation and examples. But also something clicked in my head. Is there an analogous behavior in quantum mechanical (inverting Heisenberg matrices) systems that connects to uncertainty?

Comment: I should have added - we were working on an adaptive optics problem to improve image quality. We used a laser to measure an atmospheric transfer function, and applied its inverse to a segmented mirror. Not perfectly refocused, however improved.

Comment: @docscience: Yes, it's often easier to analyze blurring in the Fourier domain, and ["The Mathematical Uncertainty Principle"](http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-uncertainty) of the Fourier transform is very similar to Heisenberg's uncertainty principle. Consider re-asking that question as a stand-alone top-level question, linking to this question.

Comment: "Unfortunately there is a loss of information because an out of focus lens acts like a linear transformation". Being a linear transformation does not mean there's loss of information. I'd reword that sentence.

Comment: @DanielSank: There is a loss of signal to noise ratio, which in physics is a coupled to a significant loss of information. Do you remember the problem with Hubble? They knew exactly what the point spread function of the mismatched mirror assembly was and it still made the instrument basically useless for most of astronomy, even though, in theory, one could have calculated the inverse but it only leads to the same result for a signal with infinite SNR. Noise gets amplified and for a quantized signal there is no telling from which directions the few photons really came from.

Comment: @DavidCary thanks for the link - very interesting - and that answers my question - conjugate variables and the scale factor. So were you thinking about a deeper question with regard to similarities? Perhaps you should post to the mainstream.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: One could formulate this as a tensor product, but I didn't want to add another layer of complexity to the problem. As you can see, my "image" is two pixels wide by one pixel high, in which case it's all the same. :-)

Comment: Wouldn't you need a third-order tensor, instead of a matrix (second-order tensor), such that each "actual" pixel can be a linear combination of the taken image? Also would this tensor vary between photographs of different scenes, especially the distance of objects relative to the camera?

Comment: @fibonatic: A tensor is just a linear transformation until we introduce a geometric meaning to it by defining it to operate between a space and itself or the space and its dual. That physical distinction doesn't exist here, so I am free to treat a two dimensional image as a vector and then the transformation becomes a simple matrix. I made use of that choice to simplify the example. The other advantage of using a matrix is that it's "human readable", while it takes a lot of experience to interpret third and higher order tensors.

Comment: I understand that signal to noise ratio and information are related. I object to the wording of the first sentence which essentially says that *any* linear transformation leads to a loss of information, which is incorrect.

Comment: @DnaielSank: Even in mathematics it depends on the linear transformation. A singular matrix loses information even in the ideal case. I pointed that out in my post. I did, however, reformulate the first sentence. If you still don't like it, you are free to make a concrete suggestion to make the post better?

Comment: I really like this answer, very much. By doing a 2-pixel case you get to use a nice small matrix. An observant reader will realize after reading this that Green's functions are just the continuous coordinate generalization of what @CuriousOne did here with matrices. Regarding the loss of information thing: I didn't like that the sentence said that loss of information happens "because ... acts like a linear transformation". That made it sound like being a linear transformation meant that you always lose information, which is false.

Comment: @DanielSank: First I wanted to do the usual blur matrix representation used by image processing software and then I realized that taking the inverse doesn't work on that directly, so I went with the smallest non-trivial "full" image, instead. I like the Green's function analogy... if only on could calculate those as easily as this toy example.

Comment: @CuriousOne I'd argue that differential equations aren't really any harder than matrix inversion :)

Comment: @DanielSank: No offense, but I would not advise you to make a bet on that... and certainly not with a mathematician who knows about the incredible subtleties of differential equations. I like Green's functions, they look so innocent, until one realizes that naive numerical integration in four dimensions can convert a desktop computer into a space heater for the rest of the week.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Bro (can I call you "bro"?), you're cheating by comparing four dimensional functions to matrices :)

Comment: @DanielSank: Cheating? Not really... I am merely referencing a painful epiphany event in my life as a young, naive student. I actually tried to solve a numerical Maxwell problem with a direct attack on the Green's function once. Needless to say, it ended in a total retreat of yours truly. :-(

Comment: Ok fine but you can find the Green function for i.e. diffraction in the far field without having to outright solve Maxwell!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35327/discussion-between-curiousone-and-danielsank).

Answer (score 8):

Unfocussing is convolving the image with a low-pass filter (that's what the optical system does to the source signal here). If high-frequencies are distroyed, you can't expect to recover them by simple algebra, since it would mean dividing by zero in the spectral domain. (filter high freqs are zero in real world, because the gaussian or the Bessel tails would be to low to make 1 bit of grey level).

Still, nowadays there are solutions to that, how unintuitive they can be. They consist in using purposely made "bad lenses" so that the Fourier transform of the "bluring filter" contains the high frequencies - and indeed, be dense in the Fourier domain - , so that you can invert them (i.e. process a "unconvolving"). Keyword is "[coded aperture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coded_aperture)", and applies to many similar cases (depth of field, motion blur, etc). Several [papers of the MIT graphics group](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/graphics/CodedAperture/) developped this.

Appart from this: Note also than under some regularising hypothesis, you can sometime also recover the high frequencies if you have multiple images (with varying view angles). This is basically how [tomography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomography) works.

Answer (score 5):

This should help: http://yuzhikov.com/articles/BlurredImagesRestoration1.htm

He is able to calculate/approximate the kernel and there is code to implement it as well which could be translated into Python.

A more precise deconvolution, 'blind deconvolution' is achieved using an iteratively tuned method with a Wiener filter that is used to take into account the randomness of noise in the image.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Be extremely careful with this link/program. As pointed out by @fabrice-neyret above, once you loose the high frequency detail, there no way to regain, unless using some artificial guess method (AI). The presented images scare me and his github page is unreachable.